Upload image to Firebase with Node.js
For some reason my code for uploading an image to firebase is not working at all.
I've tried multiple different packages for uploading like: busboy, multer, formidable, express file parser, and nothing seems to work, I usually get the same error more or less which is this:
Multer error: Error: Unexpected end of form
    at Multipart._final (/Users/xxx/Desktop/xxx/backend/functions/node_modules/busboy/lib/types/multipart.js:588:17)
    at prefinish (node:internal/streams/writable:907:14)
    at finishMaybe (node:internal/streams/writable:921:5)
    at Writable.end (node:internal/streams/writable:836:5)
    at onend (node:internal/streams/readable:946:10)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:77:11) {
  storageErrors: []
}

and this is my function code:
// Multer setup for handling file uploads (5MB limit)
const upload = multer({
    storage: multer.memoryStorage(), // Store the file in memory
    limits: { fileSize: 5 * 1024 * 1024 }, // Limit file size to 5MB
});

// Cloud Function to handle image upload
exports.updateClientProfileImg = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
    upload.single("image")(req, res, async (err) => {
        if (err) {
            console.error("Multer error:", err);
            return res
                .status(400)
                .json({ error: `File upload error: ${err.message}` });
        }

        const file = req.file;
        if (!file) {
            console.error("No file uploaded.");
            return res.status(400).json({ error: "No file uploaded" });
        }

        try {
            console.log("File uploaded:", file);

            const fileUpload = bucket.file(file.originalname);

            // Create a stream and upload the file
            const stream = Readable.from(file.buffer);
            await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                stream
                    .pipe(
                        fileUpload.createWriteStream({
                            metadata: { contentType: file.mimetype },
                        })
                    )
                    .on("finish", resolve)
                    .on("error", reject);
            });

            // Make the file public and generate the URL
            await fileUpload.makePublic();
            const imageUrl = `https://storage.googleapis.com/${bucket.name}/${fileUpload.name}`;

            return res.status(200).json({
                message: "Image uploaded successfully",
                imageUrl: imageUrl,
            });
        } catch (error) {
            console.error("Error uploading image:", error);
            return res.status(500).json({ error: "Failed to upload image" });
        }
    });
});

This is only multer, but my other codes using the other packages looked relatively the same.
Does anyone has a solution that would work with the latest version of Firebase and Node.js v20?

although my frontend is using vite react, but i test everything in postman to begin with and even there its not working

im really not sure what you're looking for here? like in postman i got to form-data, key is image and i change it file, then value i upload the file and hit send. its really not that complicated bro, postman sets the headers to multipart/form-data automatically

This question is similar to: How to perform an HTTP file upload using express on Cloud Functions for Firebase (multer, busboy). If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

See also https://github.com/firebase/firebase-functions/issues/141

I was working on a project using Firebase functions and tried implementing Multer, but it kept throwing the same error.
I ended up using this dependency express-multipart-file-parser https://github.com/cristovao-trevisan/express-multipart-file-parser, and I was finally able to process files in multipart/form-data requests.
Example:
// Middleware instance
const fileParser = require('express-multipart-file-parser');

// Endpoint logic
const uploadGuests = onRequest(async (req, res) => {
 const {
    fieldname,
    originalname,
    encoding,
    mimetype,
    buffer,
  } = req.files[0]

  // In my case I need to read a small csv file
  const csvData = buffer.toString('utf-8')

  ...
}

// Add endpoint to Express app with fileParser middleware
app.post('/upload', fileParser, uploadFn)

